# Google Custom Search while in development

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm doing a redesign for a client. On the new site I'd like to use Google Custom Search (CSE) as search engine. While I'm in development I can't let Google index the new site as it would be a horrible mess of duplication and half-done pages swimming around in Googles index.

So how do I test and refine the search result from Google CSE on my development site before launch?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Will this site be in a domain? Because otherwise there is no need to over think the indexing.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a domain"? It's eventually going to recide at www.example.com but during development and test it's at test.example.com.

Answer (score 3):

Your sites have to be added to your webmaster tools account. Once I added my test sites, I was able to crawl the pages with the site search with a robots.txt file in the index that disallows site searching.

I was able to crawl the page but to verify I checked the url in webmaster tools and it says the page is still hidden from the main google index. I added this same url to the custom search index and if found it just fine.

So this will effectively allow you to search your test site but keep it hidden from the world search.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of Nov 2016, this is still not possible.  I realize this is years after the question was asked, but I have been trying to accomplish this. This is the (disappointing) response I got from a query to Google Support.

> Google Site Search will return only those URL as result which are :
>
> 1. Added in sites to search configuration and
> 2. Indexed
>
> I would like to update you that GSS is hosted on Google's
>   infrastructure and uses the same technology as of Google.com. It is
>   not possible to get pages indexed in GSS internally but not in
>   Google's main index.
>
> GSS can index and crawl only those documents which are public and
>   accessible over internet.
>
> GSS and Google.com use same crawler and same indexing server. So, if
>   you are blocking access for google.com, your pages will not be indexed
>   and served in GSS result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid some pages of being indexed by using [robots](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

> Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about
>   their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion
>   Protocol.
>
> It works likes this: a robot wants to vists a Web site URL, say
>   http://www.example.com/welcome.html. Before it does so, it firsts
>   checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt, and finds:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

> The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The
>   "Disallow: /" tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on
>   the site.

Looking at the docs, I can't find nothing about the robots.txt, so not sure if it is honored. but looking at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing#removal) it says that you can remove it manually or set a expire date on `sitemap.xml`

Comment: The OP said **before launch**, so the website will not be online when testing. He seems to need a possibility to test it offline or at a local machine.

Comment: @w4rumy thanks, maybe I didn't understood the question? Will make some comments to try to make it clearer for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify: Preferrably I'd like to run it at a local machine, however that's not an absolute must. The live (old) site is at www.awesomesite.com and the new site that is under development is at test.awesomesite.com. So Google is able to access the test site, but I don't want the pages under test.awesomesite.com to show up in the general google index just yet. Regarding the robot.txt solution, won't that stop google CSE from index the pages for local search?